# Half-way water exit in an open water swim?

Tags: terminology, swimming

I'm trying to remember the term used for the part of a multi-lap open-water swim where the swimmer is expected to exit the water, run a distance and then enter the water in between each lap.

I'm sure there's a name for it but I just can't remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It's a term relating to triathlons and it's called an Australian Exit.

Comment: Never heard it called that before.  Have done a couple, did not know they had names!